# jQuery select an anchor inside div with numeric id attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to select all the 'a' element's id inside a div tag with id "12"?

Comment: What about `a` elements with no IDs?

Comment: You shouldn't start your IDs with a number. Generally. Don't know about HTML5

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can't have an ID starting with a number (until HTML5, anyways), but this should work:

```
$("#12 > a")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var linkIDs = $('#12 a').map(function(link) {
    return link.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: +1 but you forgot to ensure that element with the id is a `div`. If this code is ran over multiple pages, it *may* be necessary.

Comment: thanks @alex - valid point. I'm assuming the simple case and when selecting an element by id (assuming they have not been repeated like they shouldn't be), then `div#12` and `#12` should result in the same result, though `#12` will return much faster as it translates directly to `getElementById`, but `div#12` wouldn't.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me a bit. If this code is ran on two pages, and one has a `div[id=12]` and one has a `span[id=12]`, then it will select the latter too. Edge case for certain, though :)

Comment: @alex - that's true, it wouldn't be very portable in that case - but like you said edge case ;)